# How to block access by IP using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, ip

I need to block access to my site by IP address, but for some reason when I use the following I have error 500.

here is what I am trying to use:

```
#Deny Access to Adsense SPAM
Order Deny,Allow
deny from 209.51.197.0/24; # XLHOST IP
deny from 209.190.121.32/27; #XLHOST IP
deny from 209.190.0.0/17; # XLHOST IP
deny from 173.45.64.0/18; # XLHOST IP
deny from 64.79.64.0/19; # XLHOST IP
deny from 64.79.89.0/19; # XLHOST IP
deny from 64.79.85.0/19; # XLHOST IP
allow from all
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try without `;`

```
#Deny Access to Adsense SPAM
Order Deny,Allow
deny from 209.51.197.0/24 # XLHOST IP
deny from 209.190.121.32/27 #XLHOST IP
deny from 209.190.0.0/17 # XLHOST IP
deny from 173.45.64.0/18 # XLHOST IP
deny from 64.79.64.0/19 # XLHOST IP
deny from 64.79.89.0/19 # XLHOST IP
deny from 64.79.85.0/19 # XLHOST IP
allow from all
```

Comment: Worked like magic, thanks a lot, I will accept your answer as soon as I am allowed to do so

Comment: I tried your code and unfortunately it did not work for me. When I changed `Order Deny,Allow` to `Order Allow,Deny` it did work though.

Answer (score -1):

xlhost com inc uses the firefox version 27.

Put this code in your htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Firefox/27\.0 [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

[Source webmaster.net](https://www.webmaster.net/adsense/5-ways-prevent-adsense-click-bombing-xlhost-april-20-attack.html)

Comment: This is going to block access from Firefox version 27, which is not recommended as it will also block users that are still accessing site with this browser.

Comment: Yes you are right, but your solution to block each ip is not an permanent solution, best solution is to block host domain.

Comment: What if they change UA to firefox 37? will you block it too?